# Strange behavior when moving files between two SharePoint 2007 libraries using "Windows Explorer"

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I created a feature where I inherit SPItemEventReceiver to add some custom code to the ItemAdded method. The solution works as intended, except in one scenario: when I open two document libraries in "Windows Explorer" and drag the files from one library to another, the custom code only gets executed **occasionally**.

To investigate in this behavior I tried debugging, but when I do so, the custom code gets executed **every time**.

I have used this procedure to avoid properties.ListItem being null: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8712648e-cf09-4f7b-ab13-1c6aacdf588a

Do you have any thoughts on what might be the fault?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what caused the issue, but after I added the following line in the ItemAdded method, it works:

```
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

The ItemAdded event is an asynchronous event. This means the previous operation might not yet be fully completed. It is likely that it will always work in debug mode because it is a timing problem. You can try the itemAdding event or a workaround as described in: [this blog](http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-event-receivers-itemadded-null-columns-fun)